# Best way to display python script data in a webpage?

Tags: python, database, html

I have a python script that collects data on some virtual machines. I want to display this data in a webpage.The web page must be dynamic since the script will run continuously and the data must be updated every time the script runs. I possibly want this data displayed in a table but I am not sure what direction to go?

Comment: You're looking for a web server.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Apache or another web server. Set up an HTML web page with javascript. I recommend using jQuery as it makes making ajax calls so much easier. Have your javascript/ajax/jquery call your python script every x minutes/seconds.

Ensure your apache server is setup to run CGI scripts and ensure they are set with read and execute permissions.